# Reporting detailed XML errors when using QDomDocument

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qt4

I'm currently modifying some old code that is using QDomDocument to parse XML file content. Example code below:

```
QFile file(file_.filePath());   

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) 
{
    QTextStream in(&file);
    file.close();

    QString errorMsg;
    int errorLine;
    int errorColumn;

    if (!doc.setContent(in.readAll(), &errorMsg, &errorLine, &errorColumn))
    {
        qWarning("Invalid XML in file %s. Error = %s, Line = %d, Column = %d", qPrintable(file_name), qPrintable(errorMsg), errorLine, errorColumn);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the error reporting is extremely limited. Removing a closing tag half way down the file simply reports the following error:

**Invalid XML in file config.xml. Error = unexpected end of file, Line = 1, Column = 1**

Which is fairly useless.

Any suggestions of how to get more descriptive errors out of Qt's XML parsers? An accurate line number would be a good start.

P.S. I'm using Qt version 4.7.4.

Comment: `QDomDocument` is part of the old, unsupported [QtXML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html) module. Your best bet is to rewrite it using [QXMLStreamReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDomDocument::setContent` should give you the right information to know where the problem is.

For example, with this snippet of code:

```
#include <QtXml>
#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
    QFile file(":/myxml_error.xml");

    qDebug() << "File path:" << QFileInfo(file).absoluteFilePath();
    qDebug() << "File exists:" << file.exists();

    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text);

    qDebug() << "File open:" << file.isOpen();

    QDomDocument dom;
    QString error;

    int line, column;

    if(dom.setContent(&file, &error, &line, &column)){
        qDebug() << dom.toString(4);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Error:" << error << "in line " << line << "column" << column;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</Ffrom>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

We see the following error:

`Error: "tag mismatch" in line  4 column 19`

I've updated this answer after reading some comments from @kh25.

- The problem could be due to the file encoding. In this case, we could try removing carriage returns and new lines. [`dos2unix`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) can help if we're working on Linux.
- Another option would be to use an [online tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) to check the XML.

But in this particular case, it seems the problem is related to closing the file -- `file.close()` -- before calling `in.readAll()`. In this case, `QDomDocument::setContent` is reading an empty string and we see the error `unexpected end of file`.

Another way of getting the error is calling `QDomDocument::setContent` when the file has reached the end of the stream.

So, if we call for example `QTextStream::readAll()` twice, we get the same error. I.e:

```
QTextStream in(&file);
in.readAll();

if(dom.setContent(in.readAll(), &error, &line, &column)) {
    qDebug() << "Content: " << dom.toString(4);
} else {        
    qDebug() << "Error:" << error << "in line " << line << "column" << column;
}
```

@MrEricSir commented about using `QXMLStreamReader`. If you need an example, I have a little project in [GitHub](https://github.com/ftena/qxmlstreamreader) where I use that class.

Comment: This is not kh25's case I think, here the inconsistency can be detected at the not matching closing tag, while in kh25's the document is valid all down to the end, but then incomplete.

Comment: Thanks Tarod. You are 100% correct sir. For this case if you use the file directly you get much more accurate error reporting. Using a QTextStream and passing a QString into the same function resulted in a much less clear set of errors. I'm uncertain why this code was originally written to use a QTextStream (maybe earlier versions of Qt didn't support the QFile argument to setContent()) but I've updated and it is much better now. Have a markup. Perhaps someone could explain though why a QString that represents an XML block has such poor error handling.

Comment: @kh25 Oh, great! :) So the problem wasn't the encoding, but the `QTextStream`. I should update my answer, but I'd like to do some tests to verify why we get that problem if we use `QTextStream`. It seems `setContent` is only getting the last line of the file.

Comment: @kh25 I've updated my answer. Could you try not closing the file and check if the original issue happens?

Comment: Tarod I can confirm that, as you suggested, the issue is due to the file.close() being called before the in.readAll(). It is not actually an issue with the QDomDocument.setContent(). An inspection of the return value of in.readAll() when called after the file.close() simply yields a blank string and not the XML content anyway and this is why I was getting those generic errors. This is why switching to just passing in the QFile worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for reporting accurate XML errors in files is posted below:

```
QFile file(file_.filePath());

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    QString errorMsg;
    int errorLine;
    int errorColumn;

    if (!doc.setContent(in.readAll(), &errorMsg, &errorLine, &errorColumn)) {
        QString line;
        file.seek(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < errorLine; ++i) {
            line = file.readLine();
        }

        qFatal("Invalid XML encountered.\nFile %s.\nError = %s\nLine= %d\n%s", qPrintable(file_.absoluteFilePath()), qPrintable(errorMsg), errorLine, qPrintable(line.insert(errorColumn -1, "^").trimmed()));
    }
}
```